# Allow users to add existing website photo content to their own user galleries

Tags: 7, media

I'd like to have admin-driven photo galleries on my website, as well as galleries for each individual user. I'd like for my users to be able to upload images to their own galleries, but also for them to be able to select images from the admin-driven galleries and somehow pull them into / copy them to their own galleries.

Let's say I had three galleries on my site: car photos, insect photos, and fish photos. One of my users has been uploading a bunch of his/her own photos into their gallery, and they come across a really cool photo of a fish in the "Fish Photos" gallery I mentioned above. They want to add that fish photo to their own personal gallery. Yes, they could right-click>save-as and upload the photo to their gallery, but I would prefer a more automated "add this photo to my gallery" type of function.

Does anyone know of a module or some kind of other implementation that would provide this functionality?

Thanks!